# pythonで、intersectionの位置を調べる方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: python, アルゴリズム

```
#条件:データに重複は、ありません。
x = {"a", "b", "c"}
y = {"c", "b", "e"}
z = {"f", "b", "c"}
result = x.intersection(y, z)
print(result)
#{'b', 'c'}
```

出力例）おすすめの形式があれば、教えて下さい。
[['b',1,1,1], ['c',2,0,2]}

'b', 'c'を検索になりますか？1行で、書けると助かります。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: python の set 型には要素の順序保証がありませんので、変数 `x, y, z` はリストである事が前提になります。その場合は `[[i] + [t.index(i) for t in (x, y, z)] for i in set(x)&set(y)&set(z)]` です。

Answer (score 0):

私はpythonはわからないのですがrubyで書いてみました。
どなたかpythonへ翻訳お願いします。

```
x=["a","b","c"]
y=["c","b","e"]
z=["f","b","c"]

def intersection(x,*a)
    x.find_all{|i| [x,*a].all?{|j|j.include?(i)}}.collect{|i| [i]+[x,*a].collect{|j| j.index(i)}}
end

print(intersection(x,y,z))
```

Comment: `(x&y&z).map{|i| [i]+[x, y, z].map{|j| j.index(i)}}` でよいのではないかと。

Comment: うお、Arrayって&あるんですねぇ。まだまだ修行が足りませんでした。